# Microsoft Visual C# ComboBox/Listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox, listbox, numericupdown

Is it possible to have my comboBox, numericUpDown, and ListBox connected together?

I want to make the numericUpDown to be the limit of the choices that you could made taht will be displayed in the listbox.  For example:

- If numericUpDown == 2 then,
- comboBox == 5 choices.  You Can Choose 2. Your first choice shouldn't be included in your second lookthrough of the combobox. then,
- listbox == 2. (The listbox should only contain data. Depending on the value of the numericUpDown) So if the user choose again in the combobox the datas in the list box wouldn't be affected.

How might I implement this?

Comment: yes you can do all of this. you will have to work with selectedItemChanged event of combo box and for the numericUpDown I guess there is an OnChange event. start doing something than edit your question with your code and more specific questions if you are stuck on anything specific.

Comment: You need to be more specific here.  C# is a language, not a presentation framework.  Please make it clear whether you're talking about Winforms/WPF/Silverlight or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# has most of the useful controls but sometimes what you need is not there.
You can always make your own controls or just add a little coding to get what you want.
Nothing Is Impossible. 
Here is a simple way to make your own Control and then use it in your program.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/first_control.aspx